# Matrix Simplification for constraint dynamics

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems, matrix-calculus

Is, by any chance, these two formulas equivalent? x is a complex vector, and H means the complex transposition operation.
I should get from the first to the second. But it seems to me that this is not equivalent.

$ \begin{align}
 \dot x & =  \left( \mathbb{I} - A^{-T}\frac{x x^H}{x^H A^{-T} x} \right) A \, x,
 \end{align}$

$\dot x =  (\mathbb{I} - \frac{x x^H} {x^H x} )Ax \nonumber $

The second expression is obtained from the difference between the complex nx1 vector $Ax$ and the projection of $Ax$ onto x.

$\dot x = A x  - proj_x Ax$

Thanks

Edit: The context is the following, I have a dynamical system $\dot x = Ax $ that needs constraint solutions to the unit circle. Therefore, $x^ H x = 1$. The first equation was obtained by constraining the system using a lagrangian multiplier. The second is obtained by simply projecting $\dot x = Ax$ into the tangent direction of x (therefore, the motion is trapped into a circular motion of radius 1.). These expressions should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\A{A^{-T}}
\def\x{x^H}
P &= \frac{\A x\x A}{\x\A x},\qquad Q = \frac{x\x A}{\x x} \\
}$$
Note that $P\ne Q$ (unless $A$ equals the identity matrix), however
$$\eqalign{
\x P &= \x A,\qquad \x Q = \x A \\
}$$
The proposed equality reduces to
$$\eqalign{
\dot x \;=\; (A-P)x &\;\overset{?}{=}\; (A-Q)x \\
Px &\;\overset{?}{=}\; Qx \\
P &\;\overset{?}{=}\; Q \\
}$$
which is false. However, the Differential Equation (DE) can be multiplied to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\x\dot x
 &= \x Ax - \c{\x P}x \\
 &= \x Ax - \c{\x Q}x \\
 &= \x Ax - \c{\x A}x \\
 &= 0 \\
}$$
When $x$ is $\sf Real$, this is equivalent to the constraint $x^Tx=\tt1\,$ and adds nothing new.

When $x$ is $\sf Complex$, the constraint only says
$(\x\dot x = -\dot{x}^H x)$
and it is the DE which zeroes them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, just to clarify, you are saying that when x is complex, I should still use the Q matrix for the constraint? There is no sense in using P, right?

Comment: since the constraint of modulus 1 is not valid for complex vectors? I have to always use projection Q in the real and imaginary parts, right?